# Launch Samsung Dex UI natively on phone screen

Tags: android, shell, adb, root, samsung-dex

I'm trying to find a way to launch Samsung Dex on the phone screen itself, rather than via cable or wirelessly on an external monitor. Phone has root privileges.

On **Android 9**, tweaking the build.prop file was enough to make the system behaving like a Samsung tablet, hence allowing to launch Samsung Dex on the phone screen.
*ro.build.characteristics=phone* changing "phone" to "tablet"

On **Android 10** the same trick does not work.

Is there any shell command (via termux or adb) to force launch a system app like Dex and to be shown on the main phone screen (display -d1) rather than on an external screen (display -d2)
Thanks in advance for any input on this!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I've been trying for a while now to get the thing to launch without an attached display. :(

Comment: unfortunately nope.. I think this is not of much interest for people. The workaround I use to achieve something similar is using an app called Sentio. This has not been updated for a while, but the latest version still works great on Android 12. It simulates a desktop environment where apps are launched in window mode automatically and content is resized correctly. (It allows you to tweak the screen dpi from the app very nicely).
Still... it would be great if a solution to launch Dex natively would be found eventually. So please let me know if you succeed! :)